# Why is there a need to approximate gradient?

Tags: vector-analysis, approximation

There are gradient approximating methods like central difference approximation, forward approximation and backward approximation. However, I would like to understand in what situations such approximations are necessary and are helpful over the analytical method of computing gradients. I have heard that analytical gradients cannot be computed for all functions, but would like to know an example for such case so that I can understand better.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you don't really care about the precise value, then it is way faster to use differences instead of the "real" gradient.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you for your reply. Could you please also provide me an example case where numerical approximation becomes absolutely necessary?

Comment: Well, I am probably the last person you should ask... but if you give yourself pretty much any differential equation, you won't be able to find an analytic solution (or it might be quite complicated). Finding a numerical solution might be a quicker and more informative route.